# php csv import data but in one array

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

Data from CSV like below, just one column

```
| BeKwX8iN3wzHDvCaxBD1 |
| 3rPB9t6EF3RGla28YbLE |
| OAYRwbrkctcVbrXaaTef |
| N8lxYdvx47FI7eYt5FUX |
| zwtRdHr3aYYnX9avcMjX |
.....
```

file content look: https://drive.google.com/a/hiiir.com/file/d/0B4ZVHStLEPq3bklUUHkzbDN1MkE/view?usp=sharing

The code

```
$row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen($serial['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

the issue is that when I print `$num`, I got int(1), because they are all in one array()

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  "BeKwX8iN3wzHDvCaxBD1
  3rPB9t6EF3RGla28YbLE
  OAYRwbrkctcVbrXaaTef
  N8lxYdvx47FI7eYt5FUX
  zwtRdHr3aYYnX9avcMjX"}
```

I know `fgetcsv()` controll by $delimiter, and this case is `,`,but it not suitable for my case. Is it possible to separate by 20 Characters?

Comment: Seems no real CSV so why using `fgetcsv` if each line of the file looks like `|abc|` then do `array_map(function($a){ return trim($a,'|');},file($serial['tmp_name']));` to get the data in a array (one entry for reach line) or use `fgets()` instead of `fgetcsv()`.

Comment: And you can change the `$delimiter` to everthing you need, read more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use fgetcsv to read a fixed length CSV, you have to do it on you own.

[EDIT]
The problem here was not a CSV problem, it was caused by end line "\r". See comments below to deal with it.
[/EDIT]

In your case, use the delimiter params :

```
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|")
```

Your code exampled :

```
<?php

if (($handle = fopen('csv.txt', "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) {
        array_pop($data);
        array_shift($data);
        var_dump($data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Result :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) " BeKwX8iN3wzHDvCaxBD1 "
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) " 3rPB9t6EF3RGla28YbLE "
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) " OAYRwbrkctcVbrXaaTef "
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) " N8lxYdvx47FI7eYt5FUX "
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) " zwtRdHr3aYYnX9avcMjX "
}
```

Comment: Hi, `|` still not work, is the source file format problem?

Comment: I downloaded you file. It's Apple new line "\r". This is the problem here. You get 2 options : either use `ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);` in your script or first read the entire file and transform \r to \n. EDIT : If your cell delimiter is `,`, forget about the `|`

Comment: THX! ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true) it works!

Comment: If I want to transform \n to \r , I try to set $handle = preg_replace("\n","\r",$handle); before while loop, but I got  Warning   `preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: preg_replace is a regex based function. As the error says, it must not be alphanum or \. I usually use / (or # when I have / in pattern) : `preg_replace('/\n/', "\r", fgets($handle))` is what you want. For your need, str_replace("\n", "\r", fgets($handle)) would do the trick.